# How can we develop real-time capability in mobile clients interacting with a REST Api server in PHP

Tags: php, android, rest, reactive-programming

I have a REST Api server in PHP (Laravel). I need to have web and mobile clients interacting with the REST endpoints. I am using Angular for reactive updating for the web client. I would like to know how can I develop a similar reactive updates on Mobile (Android+iOS) clients in a effective/performant way.

Any examples or standards/paradigms would be great.

Comment: are you having any problem with `angular.js`???

Comment: No. I want to know how can I develop similar reactive updating on my android app.

Comment: you can use `cron jobs` or `ajax`.. or `web sockets`

Comment: For reactive update in mobile I recommend you to use GCM. Through GCM you will be able to give PUSH notification in mobile. Look at this https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) looks promising for realtime data synchronisation across clients.